What are these circles called and how big are they?
Three circles intercept the vertices and incenter of a  $\,(3,4,5)\,$ triangle.
The incircle radius is easy to predict but I don't know how to approach the other circles. At first I thought their radii were just half of their "edge" but closer inspection shows they are larger. I've tried visualizing the radii as the hypotenuse of triangles with legs of a half-edge and half-incircle radius but nothing I have tried so far works.
What are these larger circles called and how do we calculate their size and location?


Finding size and location is just a standard task of finding equation of a circle given 3 points. Not sure if these circles have a special name.

Why are you asking this question on rectangular, even specific Pythagorean, triangles and not on any general triangle?

@Dominique My interest is in Pythagorean triples and their properties. I borrow from generalizations about triangles but I have enough to study with these triples alone.

They are called incenter-excenter circles.
The diagram below shows right triangle $ABC$ with incentre $D$, on cartesian axes.

Let $r$ be the radius of the incircle. Pythagorus gives $a^2+b^2=c^2=((a-r)+(b-r))^2\implies r=\frac{a+b-c}{2}$.
So the coordinates of $D$ are $\left(\frac{a+b-c}{2},\frac{a+b-c}{2}\right)$.
The centre of the red circle through $A,D,B$ is the intersection of the perpendicular bisector of $AD$, and the perpendicular bisector of $BD$. After simplifying, we get that the coordinates of the centre are $\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$, and the radius is $\frac{c}{\sqrt2}$. So the equation of this circle is
$$\left(x-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt2}\right)^2$$
Similarly, the equation of the circle through $C,D,A$ is
$$\left(x-\frac{a-c}{2}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{b}{2}\right)^2=\left(\sqrt{\frac{c(c-a)}{2}}\right)^2$$
And the equation of the circle through $C,D,B$ is
$$\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{b-c}{2}\right)^2=\left(\sqrt{\frac{c(c-b)}{2}}\right)^2$$
To answer the OP, we can let $a=3,b=4,c=5$. (In this case, calling the three radii in increasing order $R_1,R_2,R_3$, we get the nice result $R_1R_2=R_3$.)

Your analysis is good but, in my diagram where $,c=z,,$ the radius of the circle through $,A,D,B,$ appears to be
$,\sqrt{2\bigg(\dfrac{c}{2}\bigg)^2}\approx 3.54,,$ while
$,\dfrac{c^2}{2}=12.5.\quad$
The radius $,C,D,A,$ seems like
$\sqrt{r^2+\bigg(\dfrac{b}{2}\bigg)^2}=\sqrt{5},$
while $,\dfrac{c(c-a)}{2}=5.\quad$
The radius $,C,D,B,$ seems like
$\sqrt{r^2+\bigg(\dfrac{a}{2}\bigg)^2}=\sqrt{2.5},$
while $,\dfrac{c(c-b)}{2}=2.5.$

@poetasis In my equations of the circles, the right side is the square of the radius. I have edited to show this more clearly.

Your formulas match with observation. Thank you. What drawing software do you use?

@poetasis I used www.desmos.com.

They are called incenter–excenter circles, after the incenter–excenter lemma, which states that they pass through excenters and have centers on the circumcircle of the triangle.
As you have whopping 5 pieces of data about these circles (centers and 4 points), there are many ways to calculate. For example (picture borrowed from Wiki), you can find the radius $R := |OC| = |OD|$, from it find by Pythagorean theorem $|OK|$, then $|DK|$ as $R - |OK|$, and then $DC$ by Pythagorean theorem again.


I'm sorry but I really don't understand how your diagram relates to mine. Fist we need and excircle? That would be one with K at the middle of the hypotenuse AC,  and  B being the vertex that joins the legs. Is B the same a O?  Please correct me if I am wrong and then tell me where we go from there. I know how to find the distance from B to K but nothing beyond that. I'm trying to find the diameter of the incircle-excircle from the values of x,y,z in my diagram where x,y are the axes and z is the hypotenuse.

@poetasis If $AC$ is the hypotenuse, then $K$ coincides with $O$. My suggested approach only uses lengths of sides and $R$ (which you happen to know as one of the sides is the diameter).

I still do not get what you are telling me. I have updated my diagram with labels for the vertices and edges. I am looking for the radii of the large circles. Can you relate your explanation to the (3,4,5) triangle I have shown? I've can infer by inspection how $R_2=\sqrt{2.5}$ and $R_3=\sqrt{5}$ by the Pythagorean theorem but I do not know if my inspection is accurate and I do not know how to begin finding $R_1$.

I can relate it to any triangle by means of plugging in.

E.g. $R_1 = \sqrt{2.5^2 + (2.5 - 0)^2}$ by just plugging the numbers in the formula I basically wrote.

What is the $\sqrt(2.5-0)^2$ part about? And how would YOU compute $R_2$ and $R_3$? Please use components of MY drawing because I don't understand those in your drawing.

Just to show what @Dan provided in his answer, here is how it applies to my original drawing updated with his terms. Click on the image to expand the view.

